# Asynchronous populating ListView using ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone, async-await, observablecollection, windows-phone-8.1

So, I am populating collection in async call, but I don't know why items are shown in ListView only after async method has been completed. I want them to appear gradually as items are added to ObservableCollection.

```
public FilesPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    FilesViewModel = new FilesViewModel();
    DataContext = FilesViewModel;
}

protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //here I try to populate collection
    await FilesViewModel.FillWithData(e.Parameter == null ? "" : e.Parameter as String);
}

//inside FillWithData:
var progressIndicator = new Progress<StorageItemModel>(ReportProgress);
await PopulateItems(path, progressIndicator);

private async Task PopulateItems(string path,IProgress<StorageItemModel> progress)
{
    var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
    IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> readOnlyList = await folder.GetItemsAsync();
    foreach (var item in readOnlyList)
    {
        var model = await StorageItemModel.Create(item);
        progress.Report(model);
    }

}
```

I don't know why ListView is not notified about collection change since code is, I suppose, executed on UI thread? Or it is not ?
(Items is of type ObservableCollection)

```
private void ReportProgress(StorageItemModel model)
{
    Items.Add(model);
}
```

Comment: Is `StorageItemModel.Create` actually going to take a long time, and is it actually asynchronous?  I'd expect all of the work to really be done in `folder.GetItemsAsync`, of which nothing is shown until it finishes.

Comment: No it is very fast, and it is indeed asynchronous, it opens StorageItem asynchronously and assumedly gets Thumbnail of file (also asynchronously)

Comment: You were right man, getitemsasync takes 3 seconds, thanks